# Regex failing to extract last line

Tags: python, regex

I've some pattern like this in a text file

Textfile.txt

```
----------------------
some text, Some text
some text, Some text
Line # 1
some text
Line # 2
some text
'
;
'
Line #n-1
some text
Line # n
some text
[some list]
```

My aim is to extract from

```
Line # 1
some text
Line # 2
some text
'
;
'
Line #n-1
some text
Line # n
some text
```

I used regex like so https://regexr.com/78o64

```
(Line #\s*\d+)\n(.*?)(?=\nLine #\s*\d|$)
```

I able to extract my data but it's failing to parse last line (ie, **Line #n**.
in our example **Line #69** check from link provided above). Am i doing anything wrong?. Any suggestions would be appriciated.

Comment: Something like this seems to work:
`(Line #\s*\d+)\n(.*?)(?=\n)`

Comment: I think what doesn't get matched is the "(?=\nLine #\s*\d|$)) part. That is, the lookahead for the next occurence of Line #.

Answer (score 2):

Luca's comment is a great solution:

```
(Line #\s*\d+)\n(.*?)(?=\n)
```

What's wrong with your regex is the lookahead group specifically:

```
(?=\nLine #\s*\d|$)
```

It doesn't take into account the List at the end of your data, and you're not properly "or"ing your groups together:

```
(?=\n[Line #\s*\d]|[\[.*\]$])
```

is probably closer to what you intended.
this has the look ahead looking for a new line followed by either "Line # d" or by anything between brackets before an end of line.

You want to group elements being "or"d together in square brackets as well. Otherwise you're "or"ing single character groups.

That said, Luca's suggestion is much simpler and will break less in case formatting changes in some way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SOGYMl/1)):

```
(^Line # \d+\s*)([^\n]+)
```

---

`^Line # \d+\s*` - Match "Line #" at the beginning of the line + rest of whitespaces

`[^\n]+` - match every non-linebreak character afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You could write the pattern like this, matching the line that starts with `Line #`  followed by 1 or more digits.

Then match all following lines that do not start with that pattern.

```
^Line #\s*\d+(?:\n(?!Line #\s*\d+$).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Line #\s*\d+` match `Line #` followed by optional whitespace chars and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n(?!Line #\s*\d+$)` Match a newline, and assert that the line does not start with the previous pattern
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat to match all lines

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tz0D9H/1).

Comment: Thanks for the edit and keen explination!